# Spring - Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware in dispatcher-servlet.xml

Tags: java, spring

I installed Spring Tool Suite and am now using it for a little sample project. However I keep having an error in my dispatcher-servlet.xml file:

```
Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware
```

This error is highlighted here:

```
<bean
    **class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">**
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any thought?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may have some old jar files in your configuration.  Try using the most current spring libraries.

Comment: try to mention the whole stuff which old jar files if he is using particular version of spring

Answer (score 1):

I found my self in exactly the same case when I used incompatible maven spring-dependencies i.e check [Spring Security Site](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security) on the right side where it explains what spring version should be used with what spring security version.

Answer (score 0):

The project is missing the servlet-api jar and the error can be resolved by adding the dependency in the maven pom file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put this dependency with your spring version :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **eclipse**:

1. Right click on root project -> properties.
2. Click on Deployment Assembly.
3. Click add button.
4. Double click on Java Build Path Entries and Select build path
   entries to include. (maybe if you are using maven, you need also
   include those dependencies).
5. Finally clean and build.

This worked for me.